# Mysqli Get Information from two different tables

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have two different tables one hold comments and the other user information my first mysqli_prepare statement looks like this

```
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT text,username,id,likes,dislikes FROM post WHERE school = '$sname' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10"))
```

and the other looks like this

```
   if($stmts = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE username = '$user'"))
```

basically i need to combine these two statements so that I can access both sets in the same while loop which looks like this

```
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
```

any help is appreciated thank you in advance and I will vote up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOIN operation on common field username

```
SELECT post.text,post.username,post.id,post.likes,post.dislikes FROM post 
INNER JOIN users 
ON post.username = users.username
WHERE post.school = '$sname' 
AND users.username = '$user'
ORDER BY post.id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Thank you but what if there is two different WHERE statements

Comment: I know this is a while ago but this has really helped me with my mysqli joins, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To do so with SQL you will need to combine your queries using [`JOIN`](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php).

Making some assumptions, the following is an example:

```
SELECT ... FROM post JOIN users ON post.username = users.username WHERE ...
```

**Note:** An alternative would be to `SELECT` the data separate (as you have) and *stitch* the data together with PHP. Sometimes this is preferred over a complex `JOIN`. However, what you have seems fine.

Comment: isn't username field common in both the tables

Comment: oh yes your are right so how would that look as a query statement using the join operator?

Comment: I don't know enough about your schema to properly write the `WHERE` clause. But you should be able to merge them. Just be sure to qualify your columns (e.g. **users**.username)